# Is there any way to check df -k hanging for nfs mount issues?

Tags: linux, solaris, nfs, aix, df

I am trying to write a script for such failure scenarios.

In a scenario where maybe, if remote connection is lost, `df` waits for the remote server to respond (**looks like df is hanging**). I know I could do a timeout after waiting for some seconds but is there any other way to check that `df` is hanging and kill it.

Also can I find out which mount point is causing the problem? So that I could try to `unmount` and `mount` it again.

Comment: which version you are using ? there is a bug in nfs 1:1.2.6-3 which makes mount hang when using krb5*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure following line to /etc/fstab:

```
nfs-server:/   /mnt   nfs4    _netdev,auto  0  0
```

**About _netdev**:

> where the auto option mounts on startup and the _netdev option can be
>   used by scripts to mount the filesystem when the network is available.
>   Under NFSv3 (type nfs) the _netdev option will tell the system to wait
>   to mount until the network is available. With a type of nfs4 this
>   option is ignored, but can be used with mount -O _netdev in scripts
>   later