# Cannot Remove (Unmount) Server Share (NFS) from Mount List

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, unmounting

**Note on Duplicate** - This has been marked as a duplicate quite a few times, so can someone link me to a solution which works for me? Because *everything* I've tried in all the other posts I've found, just hang forever. Thanks.

---

We have a server which has a mounted NFS share to a server which no longer exists, so this is a line from the `mount` command on server "t01":

`192.168.1.2:/test on /t02 type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=192.168.1.2,clientaddr=192.168.1.12)`

The t02 server no longer exists, it has been completely turned off and removed forever. I want to unmount it but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried the usual things suggested in posts but it's being stubborn!

If I do `umount -f -l /t02` it just hangs forever..

So I tried doing an strace on that command:

`strace umount -f -l /t02`

and I get the following:

```
close(4)                                = 0
umask(022)                              = 022
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
readlink("/t02", 0x7fff65ec9fb0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
stat("/t02",
```

Is there anything else I can do to force this to unmount? It's currently stopping me do a `df -kh` (just hangs if I try it).

Comment: So have you tried `umount -f -l --  /t02`

Comment: I hadn't tried with the --, but I've just tried and it does exactly the same, just hangs. I also tried it through strace and it shows the same as shown above :(

Comment: nfs should be mounted with `_netdev` option, now you need to find out what process are using `/t02`  example `lsof +D /t02`  or `lsof +D  / | grep t02` then try to kill those process  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88675/is-there-any-way-to-check-df-k-hanging-for-nfs-mount-issues/88677#88677

Comment: Those commands seem to hang as well! Doing an strace on the commands it stops at: `alarm(5) = 0 wait4(-1,`